# How to remove the last occurrence of a value in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How would I remove the last occurrence using init function? It is inputting a value and a list and outputting a list. I have the following code below:

```
removeLast::(Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeLast [] = []
removeLast .........
```

Comment: Closing due to lack of details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you really need to use the `init` function ? Is it some sort of homework requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets discuss the strategy:

1. find the index of the last occurence of your key
2. loop through the list and append each list element to its previous till you get to the specific index.
3. append the rest except of the element with the specific index

lets look at the code:

```
removeLast::(Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeLast a l = remove (find_last_occurrence (-1) 0 a l)  l  
    where
        find_last_occurrence :: (Eq a) => Int -> Int -> a -> [a] -> Int
        find_last_occurrence key_i _ _ [] = key_i
        find_last_occurrence key_i current_i key (x:xs) 
            | key == x = find_last_occurrence current_i (current_i+1) key xs
            | otherwise = find_last_occurrence key_i (current_i+1) key xs
        
        remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
        remove _ [] = []
        remove index  list@(x:xs) 
            | index == 0 = xs
            | index < 0 = list
        remove index  (x:xs) = x:remove (index - 1) xs
```

you can also reduce the code by:

1. swapping the list
2. loop through the list and append element to its previous till you get to the searched element
3. append the rest except of the searched element
4. swapp back the list

here's the code:

```
easyRemove :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
easyRemove key list = reverse $ remove key $ reverse list 
    where
        remove :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
        remove _ [] = []
        remove key l@(x:xs)  
            | key == x = xs
            | otherwise = x: remove key xs
```